# Issue when adding a Kendo ProgressBar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, progress-bar

When adding a Kendo ProgressBar, I get the following error:

```
CS1061: 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory<dynamic>' does not contain a definition for 'ProgressBar' and no extension method 'ProgressBar' accepting a first argument of type 'Kendo.Mvc.UI.Fluent.WidgetFactory<dynamic>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Do I have the wrong version of Kendo or MVC?

I have Kendo.MVC version 2013.2.716.340

I have MVC version 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the ProgressBar widget was introduced in Q3 which would be 2013.3.*